# Implement Calendar into Android App

Tags: android, calendar

Is there any way I can implement Androids Calendar app into an app I am making? I would like to have it so i can switch between Month view and week view just like in the calendar app. Do I have to code this all or does google provide something to help me do this?

Hey guys i fouond something that should help anyone that is looking at this thread

https://github.com/karabaralex/android-calendar-view/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to implement it yourself.

But don't forget Android is open-source, you can always look at the Calendar source code and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i fouond something that should help anyone that is looking at this thread

https://github.com/karabaralex/android-calendar-view/blob/master/README.md